# Why are there three Samba share points in my network?

Tags: samba

I set-up a [Samba](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/samba-file-server) on a local Raspberry Pi. I set the configs (to the best of my knowledge) to share only the "homes". Then when I see my networks folder from another computer, I see these three options,

[image: Samba shares]

In my directory tree, one appears as "homes on pi" and the other as "homes on pi.local". No idea where that Windows Network is coming from since there are no windows machines in the network.

On an Apple device, they show under a server "PI" with two directories as "homes, username".

Could someone help me get rid of the windows network and the multiple copies of the pi so there is only one shared directory? I really just want to share the home of the only user `username` on my pi through password and username without allowing any guests or anything. I understand this should give me only one server under network tab with only one directory for the username's home.

**Edit:** I minimised my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. Following are its contents,

```
[global]
server string = Pi
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
map to guest = Never
name resolve order = bcast host

[Public Files]
path = /home/username/public
force user = username
force group = username
create mask = 0775
force create mode = 0775
directory mask = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
public = yes
writable = yes
browseable = yes
```

Comment: You should provide details for clarity. For instance include of a copy of your Samba configuration files.

Comment: Well, that is quite a long file. Are there any specific parts that you may want to look at first?

Comment: The interesting parts

Comment: @Shōgun8 take a look.

Comment: What  is the output of the command ```testparm```?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the ***server string*** line in your config:

My ***global*** stanza  looks like this and it works as expected:

```yaml
[global]
#       workgroup = SAMBA
        security = user
        guest account = nobody
        map to guest = bad password
        passdb backend = tdbsam
```

I don't have this ***multicast*** line in my stanza, because I have commented out the ***workgroup*** line, but you could try adding this line right under your ***workgroup*** line:

```yaml
multicast dns register = No
```